# Uneven line width in drawn stroke rectangle

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, paint

I need to draw stroke rectangle with rounded corners.
here is my code:

```
mLinePaint = new Paint();
mLinePaint.setColor(mDotColorTouched);
mLinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(mLineWidth);
mLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mLinePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 
300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    RectF r = new RectF(0, 0, 300 , 300);
    c.drawRoundRect(r, 30, 30, mLinePaint);
```

but as you can see the line width is bigger in the corners...
any idea why it happens and how to fix this?

here is screen
[image]

Comment: What happens, if you comment out this line `mLinePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);`?

Comment: nope, that doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this set of code it's working.

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    RectF rectF = new RectF();
    rectF.set(5,5,250,250);
    c.drawRoundRect(rectF, 10, 10, paint);

    imgView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

[image]

Comment: if main idea of your answer was to draw smaller rectangle than bitmap - than your answer is correct.
thanks